# PowerApps application development (custom code)

Tags: c#, .net, powerapps

I have traditionally built applications in C# and .net framework, but I am looking to move to Power Apps.

I'm need to write a script that takes some information from table1 and copies it to table2 on a button press.

Traditionally I would have written this  in C# using a SQL dB connector.

How would I achieve the same thing using PowerApps and a Dataverse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Automate to achieve this : you can run a flow from a button press within PowerApps, here's the documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/using-logic-flows

Good day

Answer (score 0):

As @Nackoo said, you can use Power Automate to automate a task such as this, especially because Power Automate allows SQL Stored Procedures. You could also use *PowerApps* as a UI where users can choose which [Stored Procedure *Power Automate* should execute](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Stored-procedure-and-powerapps/td-p/683375).

But if you really want to use PowerApps ONLY, there is a [SQL Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-sqldatabase) (API wrapper) that you can try.

**Note:**

1. This is a premium connector. Each user of the app will need a premium license.
2. If your copy command will **ever** be more than 2000 records, this gets way more complicated and you'd likely try a different avenue.

**PowerApps pseudocode / setup:**

0. Optional: Change the `Data Row Limit` to 2000
   [image]
1. Add a `Button` control to the PowerApps Studio canvas
2. Change the `OnSelect` property to something like:

```
//This collects records from SQL_TABLE_1

ClearCollect(colTable1,
    Filter(SQL_TABLE_1,        //This is your SELECT clause
        <column> = <criteria>  //This is your WHERE clause
    )
);

//This patches records into SQL_TABLE_2

ForAll(colTable1,
    Patch(SQL_TABLE_2,
        Defaults(SQL_TABLE_2),
        {
           <column1_in_colTable1>: <column1_in_sqltable2>,  //"< >" = actual column names
           <column2_in_colTable1>: <column2_in_sqltable2>,
           <columnN_in_colTable1>: <columnN_in_sqltable2>
        }
    )
)
```